# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, address issues and lead the way in site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community's issues are properly addressed.

[image: Sean Owen]
[image: Sean Owen]
[image: Sean Owen]
[image: Sean Owen]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are many members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections after your site makes it through graduation.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. This is a learning experience for everyone.

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations to all of you!  And good luck in moving forward.

Things have grown significantly in the short time that I've been around - I think the number of questions has doubled and the number of daily visitors has grown nearly 10-fold.

I'm happy to help out in other ways as time permits, and I'm sure many others are as well.

Here's to hoping we can make it through graduation!

Answer (score 3):

Moderators, moderate thyself! I just notice I've flagged quite a few of their questions as being off-topic because they should be on stats.stackexchange.com, or are way too discursive with no good answer and full of opinion. Will they do this?
It will improve the data science quality on the site, which is what we all want, right?

Comment: Thou canst keep thy heart in peace, for we cometh but to help, and do shall we the best we can. :)

Comment: Let's keep in mind that everyone on this still-very-new site is determining _together_ what is and isn't off-topic. If you'd like to have some constructive debate to get everyone on the same page, meta is just the place to do it. But please, bring specific matters up in their own separate questions. It's important to keep the purpose of each meta thread clear.

Comment: If you have a strong opinion of what the content of this site should contain, lead by example.  Ask good questions, provide good answers.  Discuss the kinds of things that you feel should be DataScience here in meta.  There are going to be areas of crossover between stackexchange sites.

Comment: It would really help if you could go ahead and start a discussion on some specific examples as that would lead to the formulation of clearer guidelines about the scope. Personally, I think the line between DS, Statistics and pure programming in the context of languages such as R, is not very clear and that needs to be discussed.

Comment: Then a chat room is the place for discussion. This is a place for questions and answers.

Comment: The user doth protest too much, methinks.